# Conditionally Counting a Response Across Multiple Variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I am fairly comfortable programming in R but am working on a scholarly statistical analysis that my PI would much prefer would be done in SAS.  I am using SAS University Edition and thus cannot use the new submit / R to do the things I am uncomfortable doing in SAS.  In any case, I am trying to conditionally count the frequency of a given character result across multiple columns.  using the below toy data set:

```
DATA example;
INPUT X01_d3 $ X02_d3 $ X03_d3 $ X04_d3 $;
CARDS;
H H F D
H H H H
H D D D
F F F D
F F D D
H . . .
H F . D
;
RUN;
```

I am wanting to count the number of times that "H" appears for a given observation and put it into a new variable called Num_H.  How I would typically code this in R would be:

```
example$Num_H<-rowSums(example[,1:4] == "H")
```

giving me the following output:

```
> example
  X01_d3 X02_d3 X03_d3 X04_d3 Num_H
1      H      H      F      D     2
2      H      H      H      H     4
3      H      D      D      D     1
4      F      F      F      D     0
5      F      F      D      D     0
6      H      .      .      .     1
7      H      F      .      D     1
```

I could easily write this in a data step using if/then statements but based on the size of the data set I would prefer not to.  Is there and easier way to do this in SAS in a DATA step, PROC SQL, or otherwise? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off: in using SAS vs R, you're going to find things that are easier to do in one versus the other all the time.  Since R is a matrix language, and Base SAS is not, things like 'scan every element in this list ...' will be one of the things R does more efficiently than SAS.

That said, there's an easy way to do this:

```
data want;
  set example;
  num_h = lengthn(trimn(compress(cats(of _character_),'H','k')));
run;
```

COMPRESS eliminates characters not 'H' and then the other things make it so it works properly (trimn/lengthn make it so it doesn't count empty ' ' as one, cats takes all of the char variables and makes them a single string).

If your data were more complicated, where you couldn't use this trick (such as multiple character strings), you could certainly loop over the variables to get your result.

```
data want;
  set example;
  array xvars x01_d3 -- x04_d3;
  do _i = 1 to dim(xvars);
    num_h = sum(num_h, xvars[_i]='H');
  end;
  drop _i;
run;
```

A little longer of course to write, but gets the job done pretty easily.

Comment: That array language was exactly what I was looking for, I just put that into a macro and it worked like a charm, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate option, if you are using SAS University Edition, you have access to SAS/IML, which is SAS's matrix language (i.e., similar to R).  IML isn't identical to R, and you'll still have some issues adjusting to it undoubtedly, but it *is* a matrix language, so you'll probably find this a bit easier.

Here's the IML program that would produce the vector you're asking for.

```
proc iml;
  use work.example;
  read all var _CHAR_ into char_mat;
  for_num_h = countc('H',char_mat)[,+];
  print for_num_h;    
quit;
```

Here, I apply the SAS function `countc` to generate a matrix of 1/0 (it's done at the cell level); then use the [subscript reduction operator for addition](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#workmatrix_sect14.htm) to sum them into a vector.

Comment: By the way, if you find `SAS/IML` useful, you might add it as a tag to the question ([tag:sas-iml]), in which case some others might chime in with potentially better answers; the SAS/IML developer follows the tag, among others.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
   Data want;
    set example;
    Num_H = sum((X01_d3="H"), (X02_d3="H"),(X03_d3="H"),(X04_d3="H"));
   run;
```

In fact (X01_d3="H") creates a dummy variable 0/1. So all you have to do is to sum this values!

Hope it helps!

MK